# ban command if member is None: [discord.py]

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User, reason =None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.channel.send("I have no one to ban")
        return
    if member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("you can't ban yourself")
        return
    await ctx.guild.ban(member)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} was banned")
```

this is my code

I need to fix:

```
    if member is None:
        await ctx.channel.send("I have no one to ban")
        return
```

error :

member is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: What is the question here? Do you just get the console output but not your defined message?

Comment: @Dominik

do not work         I need to fix:       
    if member is None:
        await ctx.channel.send("I have no one to ban")
        return

Answer (score 2):

Put the default value of `member` as None like this, then it won't be a required arg anymore

```py
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User = None, reason =None):
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```py
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
        await ctx.send('I could not find that member...')
```

This is a error handler

It also prevents member logging :D